# I'm programming a BowlingScores program.

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a bowling scores program where I enter an array of nicknames for bowlers and then make a parallel 2D array of their scores for 4 rounds. Then at the end I should be able to print their scores and the average of their scores. However, the code that I have for the average loops through every number and divides it by four. Each time it is also adding the number to the previous number. 
The toString method also isn't working.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BowlingScores {
public void printScores()
 {
 String[] nicknames = {"Kylie", "Caitlyn", "Kim", "Kanye"};


int[][] scores =  
{{145, 167, 183, 193},
{76, 84, 92, 104},
{77, 177, 182, 196},
{300, 300, 300, 300}};

int sum = 0; 

for(int index = 0; index < scores.length; index++)
for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{

        sum = sum + scores[index][j];
        int average = sum/ scores.length; 




     System.out.println("");



    System.out.print(nicknames[index] + " bowled rounds of " + scores[index] + " and had an average of " + average);








}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what the scores for Kylie are? Is it `{145, 167, 183, 193}` or is it `{145, 76, 77, 300}`?

Comment: The scores for Kylie are {145, 167, 183, 193}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve both your aggregation problem and the `toString()` issue:

```
for (int index = 0; index < scores.length; index++) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < scores[index].length; j++) {
    sum = sum + scores[index][j];
  }
  int average = sum / scores[index].length;
  System.out.println(nicknames[index] + " bowled rounds of "
      + Arrays.toString(scores[index])
      + " and had an average of " + average);
}
```

Note that `toString()` on arrays directly doesn’t work as might be expected. Instead you should use an explicit `java.util.Arrays.toString()`.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can also mark this answer as accepted (with the green check mark) and/or mark it as useful (using the up arrow) :-)